# Meteor.js: How to set a div height dynamically via Javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor, handlebars.js, dom-events

I'm using templates/handlebars but none of the event handlers are triggered when the browser window resizes. Not sure how to capture the resize event in order to dynamically set the div's height to be within the viewport

Here's a sample of what I've tried so far using meteor's event map:

```
Template.basic.events({
    'resize window' : function(evt, tmpl){
         alert("test");
     },
};
```

Ideally this handler would be called each time the window is resized so I can use `$(window).height()` to set the div's height in the html using `tmpl.find('#main-div');`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most problems which directly rely on jQuery can be solved using the [onRendered](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) callback like so:

```
Template.basic.onRendered(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    console.log($(window).height());
  });
});
```

Technically this works, but because `window` never gets removed as part of the rendering process, this technique has a big disadvantage: it adds a new resize handler **every time** the template is rendered.

Because `window` is always available, you can instead use the `created` and `destroyed` callbacks to register and unregister the handlers:

```
Template.basic.onCreated(function() {
  $(window).resize(function() {
    console.log($(window).height());
  });
});

Template.basic.onDestroyed(function() {
  $(window).off('resize');
});
```

Note, however, that stopping the resize handler in [onDestroyed](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onDestroyed) may not really be what you want. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268424/removing-the-window-resize-event-in-jquery) question for more details.

Also note that in the current version of meteor, you can check the number of event handlers like so:

```
$._data($(window).get(0), "events").resize.length
```