# Prevent Browser window resizing

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to come up with a solution to stop browser resizing at a certain width. Just for testing I am using the following directive:

```
admin.directive('stopResizing', function ($window) {
return {
    link: function (scope, elem) {
        angular.element($window).on('resize', function (event) {                
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
    }
};
});
```

I am successfully catching the event but my code has no effect - the window is still resizing. I tried using CSS approach like body's min-width but it did not work either. This is the body tag:

```
<body stop-resizing style="min-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt any browser is going to allow you that level of control unless it is some kind of web-page-as-an-app framework like Electron.

Comment: Instead of focusing on the browser resizing, focus on keeping your content from resizing inside the bigger or smaller window.  Its up to the user to decide how big their browser is

Comment: If you try resizing Chrome Settings window horizontally you will see what I am asking for.

Answer (score -1):

```
angular.element(window).off("resize", function()
{
    elem.css("min-width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;")
});
```

Comment: Nope. Here's the [documentation for `off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/). It removes an existing event handler.

Comment: can you please check with this- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268424/removing-the-window-resize-event-in-jquery

Comment: That answer is using the method as per the documentation - to remove a function which was attached with `on`.