# How to remove a window resize Listener in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, event-listener

I want to remove an Event Listener one some website using JS.
[image: even listener]

When I use the following code as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13268424/removing-the-window-resize-event-in-jquery), it doesn't work. I throws millions of error messages in the console.

```js
$(window).off("resize");
```

I also added jQuery in the console using following code:

```js
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... give time for script to load, then type (or see below for non wait option)
jQuery.noConflict();
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can only remove an event listener if you know the event and have a reference to the event handler function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const { resize } = getEventListeners(window);

resize.forEach(({ listener }) => {
  window.removeEventListener('resize', listener);
});
```

The above should result in removing all of the `resize` listeners attached to the `window`.

The [getEventListeners](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#geteventlisteners) is a utility function that is not a part of the JavaScript spec. I wouldn't use that in code meant for production.

Another idea that looks worth looking into instead of `getEventListeners` is intercepting the `addEventListener` function.

```
const addEventListener = window.addEventListener;

window.addEventListener = (...args) => {
  if (args[0] === 'resize') {
    console.log('Resize event attached!', args[1]);
  }
  addEventListener(...args);
}
```

We could even go a bit further and block all of the resize event handlers from attaching.

```
const addEventListener = window.addEventListener;

window.addEventListener = (...args) => {
  if (args[0] === 'resize') {
    console.log('Resize event trying to attach, but it is being blocked');
  } else {
    addEventListener(...args);
  }
}
```

Maybe the above is somehow useful in your case.

Comment: It's working! Much thanks, you're the goat ❤️ I believe that it deletes all the resize listeners though, but in my case it doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you know though how to make it work from outside the console? Apparently `getEventListeners` is the console API. When I run it in my Chrome Extension's `content.js` script, it shows an error that 'getEventListeners is not defined'. I just read what you wrote under the code sample haha, how would I do it in prod. then?

Comment: Looks like `getEventListeners` is a part of the "Console Utilities" that run only in the console, unfortunately.

Comment: @TacoHemingway I modified my answer above to include an idea with intercepting the `addEventListener` function. This way you can also catch the event listeners that are being attached.

Comment: I'll look into the code, it might be of use to me. Thank you!